# Syntax error with the execution of SQL query, I am unable to find, kindly let me know whats the error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting syntax error as `syntax error near : "("`, when I execute the below code. I am unable to find out what's the error.

My query:

```
Select id, name, AVG(salary) over (order by salary) as aver from test;
```

Comment: Are you sure that's your whole query? I just ran exactly the same query locally and there are no syntax issues.

Comment: are there further columns in your table? 
what do you expect to receive from your query?

Comment: What version of sql server are you on (Select @@version )

Comment: Yes, this is the exact query which I am running....

Comment: i checked the query too. it's running without syntax errors.
if you wanna check it, i created a SQLFiddle here
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f668d/1

Comment: @Esteban: thanks it's working.

Comment: @Esteban thank u so much....

Comment: @HarshithaYadav you're welcome. i posted the SQL statement from the SQLFiddle as answer too. so the question finally has an working answer.

Answer (score 0):

example with testdata and your statement.
it's working without syntax errors:

```
CREATE TABLE test
( id int
 ,name varchar(20)
 ,salary int
  )
;

INSERT INTO test VALUES (1,'John', 2500);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (2,'Jack', 3500);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (3,'William', 4500);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (4,'Avarel', 7200);

Select id
      ,name
      ,AVG(salary) 
  over (order by salary) as aver 
  from test;
```

Answer (score -3):

You need to modify your query this way

```
Select id, name, AVG(salary)  as over from test order by salary;
```

Maybe it'll be helpful.

Comment: That's really not the way to fix it.